# ArgumentError in Topics#show Possible Devise error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm a bit of a rails newb here and need some help figuring this out. I have an argument error that is thrown every time I try and create or edit a new "topic."

[ArgumentError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7Gj.png)

Here is the code for the "show:"

```html
<h1><%= @topic.title %></h1>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_path(@topic), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Delete Topic", @topic, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this topic?'} %>
<% if policy(Bookmark.new).create? %>
  <%= link_to "New Bookmark", new_topic_bookmark_path(@topic), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
<% @topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="http://icons.better-idea.org/icon?url=<%= bookmark.url %>&size=120">
          <div class="media-heading">
            <%= link_to bookmark.name, topic_bookmark_path(@topic, bookmark) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <%= render partial: 'likes/like', locals: {bookmark: bookmark} %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the "topics" controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
  end

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice]= "Topic was saved."
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash.now[:alert]= "The topic could not be saved. Please try again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.assign_attributes(topic_params)

    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice]= "The topic was saved sucessfully."
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash.now[:alert]= "There was an error saving the topic. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])

    if @topic.destroy
      flash[:notice]= "\"#{@topic.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to topics_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error in deleting this topic."
      render :show
    end
  end

  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

Update(1): New error after deleting "policy" [New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BrPb.png)

Here is the "application policy that uses Pundit:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.present? && ( record.user == user )
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.present? && (record.user == user)
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post the error that you are getting

Comment: The argument error is a link to the picture. http://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7Gj.png

Comment: Did you try without policy? (only `link_to "New Bookmark"..`)

Comment: I have not. I'll try it now.

Comment: I deleted policy. I have updated the original post to reflect the new error.

Comment: @bobbystouket Any ideas? I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with Policy made with the Pundit gem. Can you check something called the BookmarkPolicy or something similar, or at least post that here. Did you forget to  `include Pundit` in your controller ?

Comment: Adding include <code>Pundit</code> Does not help the error. I will update the original code with the BookMark policy.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the application policy. There is no policy specific to Bookmarks. The application controller has include Pundit

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Pundit gem but I don't see the authorize method in your controller. From [Pundit's documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit):

> Supposing that you have an instance of class Post, Pundit now lets you
>   do this in your controller:

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

> The authorize method automatically infers that Post will have a
>   matching PostPolicy class, and instantiates this class, handing in the
>   current user and the given record.

Answer (score 0):

The source code in the screenshot and the code you posted is not the same. Your code:

```
<% if policy(Bookmark.new).create? %>
```

Screenshot:

```
<% if (Bookmark.new).create? %>
```

Rails is correctly reporting that `Bookmark.new` does not have a `create?` method, because it's missing the `policy()` method call.

Is your file saved? Are you sure you're changing the correct file?